# How to access field on an array in cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this cloud function that creates a new document every time I have a new chat. I am trying to access the values on the `messages` array, but I got `undefined` on the console log.

here is my document on firebase:

[image]

I am trying to access the `messages` with `lastMessage = data.messages` to create a new document with these values on my function:

```
exports.onConversationCreated = functions.firestore.document('chat/{chatId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  let data = snapshot.data();
  let chatId = context.params.chatId;

 if(data){
    let members = data.members;
    let lastMessage = data.messages;
    for(let index = 0; index < members.length; index++){
        let currentUserId = members[index];
        let remainingUsersId = members.filter((u) => u != currentUserId);
        console.log(lastMessage.message);
        remainingUsersId.forEach((m) => {
            return admin.firestore().collection('authUsers').doc(m).get().then( (_doc) => {
                let userData = _doc.data();
                if(userData) {

                    return admin.firestore().collection("authUsers")
                    .doc(currentUserId).collection('chat').doc(m).create({
                        "chatId": chatId,
                        "image": userData.photoUrl,
                        "name": userData.displayName,
                        "unseenCount": 0,
                        "lastMessage": lastMessage.message,
                        "timestamp": lastMessage.timestamp,
                        "type": lastMessage.type
                    });
                }
                return null;

            }).catch(() => {return null});
        })
    }
  }
  return null;
});
```

I am trying to access the value `message` which is in the `messages` array, but I get `undefined` on the console log, do you guys know how I can access it?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you expect the log to print instead of undefined.  Bear in mind that `lastMessage` is an array and it doesn't have a property called `message`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `messages` field is an Array with one element, exactly like the `members` field is an Array with two elements. We can see that from the screenshot of your Firestore database: `members` has two elements (of type String), indexed with `0` and `1`, and `messages` has one element (of type Map), indexed with `0`.

You therefore need to access it as follows:

```
let lastMessage = data.messages;
//....
console.log(lastMessage[0].message);
```

It is not clear, from the content of your question, if there is any specific reason for defining the `messages` field as an Array. Are there any cases when you have several elements? If no, you should probably directly save the `messages` data as a Map.

---

In addition, note that you are incorrectly managing the life cycle of your Cloud Function. You should return a Promise when all the asynchronous work is completed. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details.

Since you are executing a variable number of calls to Firebase asynchronous methods in a `forEach` loop, you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Renaud thanks for your contribution, the reason why it's an array is because every map will be a message in the chat, while there are two ```members``` fixed, there may be undefined number of messages. I do need to access only the first one. Unfortunately I tried your solution but It has returned ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined```.

Comment: @RicardoOscarKanitz I've double checked, it should work.  `const data = doc.data(); const lastMessage = data.messages; console.log(lastMessage[0].message);` will print "bo" in the log. Are you sure the error you encounter is corresponding to this code?

Comment: I agree, it should work, the same way I'm accessing the ```members``` it should access the ```messages``` field. I'm pretty sure this is the code ```onConversationCreated
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined at exports.onConversationCreated.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:240:36) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:134:23) at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/...```

Comment: What do you get with `const data = doc.data(); const lastMessage = data.messages; console.log(lastMessage);`?

Comment: I got ```onConversationCreated
ReferenceError: doc is not defined at exports.onConversationCreated.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:233:18) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:134:23) at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:199:28) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my previous comments. I meant `const data = snapshot.data(); const lastMessage = data.messages; console.log(lastMessage);`. And the same mistake was also in the previous comment above.... You should read `const data = snapshot.data(); const lastMessage = data.messages; console.log(lastMessage[0].message);`

Comment: No need to be sorry Renaud, I tried both ways but none works. Would you mind sharing your code so I can check what the difference is?

Comment: @RicardoOscarKanitz You should first confirm that `snapshot.data();` is what you expect. Just remove anything in your Cloud Function and replace it with `const data = snapshot.data(); console.log(data); return null;` What do you see in the Cloud Function console?

Comment: Thanks Renaud for your suggestion, I printed ```data``` and I got this ```onConversationCreated
{ members:
[ 'ahRXO99l6PelxENLYXPFZxRvalc2',
'tXzaqmBHk4QZr42N5Hxp4SqJ5kE3' ],
messages: [],
ownerId: 'ahRXO99l6PelxENLYXPFZxRvalc2' }``` so my messages array seems to be empty I don't know why

Comment: @RicardoOscarKanitz We are progressing! :-) Do you see it empty in the Firestore console? Also, what do you get if you do `const data = snapshot.data(); console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); return null;`

Comment: Renaud yes, it is empty on the Functions console, here is what ```JSON.stringify(data)``` returns, ```onConversationCreated
{"ownerId":"ahRXO99l6PelxENLYXPFZxRvalc2","messages":[],"members":["ahRXO99l6PelxENLYXPFZxRvalc2","tXzaqmBHk4QZr42N5Hxp4SqJ5kE3"]}```, ```messages``` is an empty array, but it should contain my map information right?

Comment: So yes, we can conclude that messages is an empty array. "but it should contain my map information right?" => it all depends on how you store/write it. You may share this code, but FYI I'm going to bed... I'll have a look tomorrow morning.

Comment: thanks Renaud, it didn't work the way I was expecting but you helped me finding the problem on my code. I found out I was storing an empty array, that's why it was empty. Sorry for my dumbness, now I know what I have to fix. Thanks a lot!